# Выборка места в топе SQL

Tags: php, sql

столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне нужно получить цифру места конкретного столбца из выборки.
Т.е я делаю запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY money DESC
```

И вот к примеру этот человек на 10 месте, как мне получить эту 10?

Comment: например посчитать количество человек у которых money больше, чем у требуемого, т.е. `select count(1) from table where money > (select money where id=X)`. И не помешало бы эту информацию кешировать, потому что пересчет записей может быть медленным и ресурсоемким

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, ваш вариант сработал

Comment: @Mike Ваш вариант работает, но немного не совсем как нужно, если человек на 813 месте в топе, этот запрос видит его в 743 каким-то образом, не знаю, магия

Comment: А это надо смотреть что делать если есть кто то с точно таким же money. Если у вас у 10 человек money=100 то как определить кто из них на каком месте ? вот как определитесь с полем по которому вместе с money можно гарантировать уникальность места, добавьте условие вроде `or (money=(money-искомого) and ID > ID-искомого`

Comment: Можете скинуть полный запрос? Просто немного не ясно.

Comment: не могу. У вас в вопросе сортировка только по одному полю. Она предполагает неопределенность места в случае если есть одинаковые money.

Comment: @Mike Но как тогда ORDER BY понимает на каком месте человек, у которого money так же, как и у 100 ниже?

Comment: А order by и не понимает. Его вывод для одинаковых записей "случаен". Он может быть продиктован например тем, как записи легли на диск. но любая модификация записи, даже не связанная с полем money теоретически может изменить этот порядок и место изменится, без изменения money. Вот поэтому вы и должны принять решение, на основе чего вы еще хотите что бы работали места, что бы обеспечить стабильность. И да, конечно id зписи не худший вариант, но мне бы например было бы обидно что у меня при money=100 место 813, а другого чувака с таким же money оно почему то 743 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте оконные функции если есть или

```
Select * 
From ( SELECT t.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number
 FROM table t, 
   (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
 ORDER BY money DESC ) as data
where row_number = 10
```

Можете использовать в место 10 то что вам нужно

Comment: У меня данный запрос не работает, и видимо он работает если у него топ 10, а мне эту 10 нужно найти.

Comment: На самом деле он нумерует вывод по условию сортировки и выводит только 10 запись. Какую бд вы используете?

Comment: Возьмите и запустите запрос на самой базе данных. Какую ошибку она скинула?

Comment: innoDB, версия mysql 5.7, WITH только 8+

Comment: А так попробуйте.

Comment: Работает, но прикол, в том что мне нужно получить row_number, а вы его передаете

Comment: Дальше думаю напильником можно поработать. :)))

Comment: К стати можете удалить условие where совсем и получите пронумерованные записи

Comment: Боже, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table
ORDER BY money
OFFSET n rows

Где n - количество пропущенных строк
В Вашем случае n=9

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY money DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " - Money: " . $row["money"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

На php можно сделать так. Вообще как я понял, у вас в таблице должна быть колонка с номером топа и потом в цикле вы можете вывести эти данные.

Comment: Вы не поняли суть вопроса, мне из выборки 10 человек по топу, нужно взять место определенного человека, к примеру человек на 5 месте в выборке, и мне нужно как-то определить что он на 5 месте. И полностью без цикла, это на подобии профиля игрока, где есть колонка с местом его топа.